# Find object by realm.js

Tags: react-native, realm

Hello I use realm database with react-native.

I have `Item` schema and find one item by id.

```
var items = realm.objects('Item');
var item = items.filtered('id == $0', item_id);
console.log(item.name); // It should be printed name, but undefined
```

I can't find item. so use lodash.

```
var item = _.find(realm.objects('Item'), _.matchesProperty('id', item_id));
console.log(item.name); // print "ABCD"
```

How do I get item by id?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`filtered` returns a `Results` object which is very similar to a javascript `Array`.

So your code should be:

```
var items = realm.objects('Item').filtered('id == $0', item_id);
var item = items[0];
console.log(item.name); // should print the name
```

Answer (score 2):

`realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Item', item_id)`

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `objectForPrimaryKey` function but must set **primaryKey** you schema

**Set primarykey**

```
const BookSchema = {
  name: 'Book',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id:    'int',    // primary key
    title: 'string',
    price: 'float'
  }
};
```

### **Usage**

`const findObject = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Item', item_id);`